# Ignoring new line characters in PLY/Yacc Productions

Tags: python, newline, yacc, lex, ply

I'm trying to implement a struct in my grammar (in PLY). The parser generates no syntax errors if I write my struct on one line but if I write it on multiple lines it produces syntax errors on the lines containing braces. My code follows (without ast.py because I don't think it's helpful):

## main.py

```
from parser import *
import ply.yacc as yacc
yacc.yacc()

def main():
    with open('main.smp') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            try:
                yacc.parse(line)
            except EOFError:
                break           

main()
```

## parser.py (contains lexing code as well)

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"../..")

from ast import *

tokens = (
    'NAME', 'NUMBER', 'STRUCT', 'LBRACE', 'RBRACE'
    )

literals = ['=','+','-','*','/', '(',')', '{', '}']

# Tokens
t_NAME   = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
t_LBRACE = r'\{'
t_RBRACE = r'\}'

def t_NUMBER(t):
    r'\d+'
    try:
        t.value = int(t.value)
    except ValueError:
        print "Integer value too large", t.value
        t.value = 0
    return t

def t_STRUCT(t):
    r'struct '
    return t

t_ignore = " \t"

def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)
    print "new line"

def t_error(t):
    print "Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0]
    t.lexer.skip(1)

# Build the lexer
import ply.lex as lex
lexer = lex.lex()

lexer.brace_count = 0

# Parsing rules
precedence = (
    ('left','+','-'),
    ('left','*','/'),
    ('right','UMINUS'),
    )

start='statement'

def p_statement_assign(p):
    'statement : NAME "=" expression'

    names[p[1]] = p[3]

def p_statement_struct(p):
    "statement : STRUCT NAME LBRACE statement RBRACE" 
    print "parsed struct"

def p_statement_expr(p):
    'statement : expression'

    try:
        print p[1].codegen()
    except AttributeError:
        print p[1], "no attribute"

def p_expression_binop(p):
    '''expression : expression '+' expression
                  | expression '-' expression
                  | expression '*' expression
                  | expression '/' expression'''

    p[0] = BinOpNode(p[1], p[3], p[2])

def p_expression_uminus(p):
    "expression : '-' expression %prec UMINUS"

    p[0] = NumNode(-p[2])

def p_expression_group(p):
    "expression : '(' expression ')'"

    p[0] = NumNode(p[2])

def p_expression_number(p):
    "expression : NUMBER"

    p[0] = NumNode(p[1])

def p_expression_name(p):
    "expression : NAME"

    try:
        p[0] = names[p[1]]
    except LookupError:
        print "Undefined name '%s'" % p[1]
        p[0] = 0

def p_error(p):
    try:
        print "{1}: Syntax error on '{0}'".format(p.value, lexer.lineno)
    except AttributeError:
        print "{0}: Syntax error on line".format(lexer.lineno)
```

## main.smp

```
struct test 
{
    9+9   
}
```

## output

```
new line
2: Syntax error on line
2: Syntax error on '{'
new line
new line
18
4: Syntax error on '}'
```

Comment: I think that the action for `p_expression_uminus` is incorrect, since `p[2]` might in that case be an AST node (eg., if the expression is `-(a+b)`). But that's not relevant to your question.

Comment: Thanks that may be correct and I will investigate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main loop:

```
def main():
    with open('main.smp') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            try:
                yacc.parse(line)
            except EOFError:
                break
```

is deliberately parsing each input line separately. So each line would need to be a complete `statement` in order for the parse to succeed (for that line).

Comment: In fact that seems to be the problem. I instead parsed the entire string however now I get a syntax error on the final line only, the '}'. I'll investigate that further and try to determine if that's related.

Comment: After fixing it to parse the entire file instead of line by line I get these errors:

**struct test { \n
    9 \n
}**
`1: Syntax error on '}'`

**struct test { 9 }**
`1: Syntax error on '{'`

Comment: @BennetLeff: That might be because putting `{` and `}' as literals and as patterns confuses the scanner generator. I'd just make them literals and refer to them in the grammar with a literal syntax (like `=`), since that's simpler and more readable.

Comment: It seems like it was something small like that, I made a new file and rewrote my code and it ran just fine.